# @WebServiceRef wsdlLocation can not refer to a classpath entry in JBoss EAP 7 / Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wsdl, wildfly

When injecting a webservice client with @WebServiceRef in JBoss EAP, the wsdl is not found by the app server. The webservice client has been generated and the wsdl is bundled with the jar file. When trying to refer to the classpath of the wsdl in the wsdlLocation attribute of the @WebServiceRef annotation, JBoss will produce the following exception:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: WFLYWS0039: Child '/wsdl/mywsdlfile.wsdl' not found for VirtualFile: "/C:/jboss/standalone/deployments/mywebapp.war"

How do I correctly refer to the wsdl which resides in the webservice client jar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<wsdlLocation>/WEB-INF/classes/wsdl/*</wsdlLocation>
```

Works in my case.

Regards.

Comment: In wish file do you pour this tag plz?